# Getting an undeclared identifier error for "i"

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height;
    do
    {
        // Asking for # of blocks
        height = get_int("Height: ");
    }

    // Setting min/max height
    while (height < 1 || height > 8);

    // For columns
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)

        // For spaces
        for (int j = height - 1; j > i; j--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

            // For the #'s
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }

printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Because `i` is not in scope of the 3rd loop.

Comment: Always, **always**, ***always*** wrap your for-loops in `{`...`}`.

Comment: work on your indendation skills

Answer (score 4):

C is not Python.

This code

```
// For columns
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)

    // For spaces
    for (int j = height - 1; j > i; j--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

        // For the #'s
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
```

is equivalent to

```
// For columns
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    // For spaces
    for (int j = height - 1; j > i; j--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
}

// For the #'s
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
{
    printf("#");
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate further on what you mean by that aside from the obvious? Just so that I can fully understand why I'm making the mistake and how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Like I completely understand that my indentation was off by a lot, but being a complete beginner I'm still having a hard time picking out those problems and understanding how to fix them, and I hate just getting the answer.

Comment: plus that didn't work. I'm still getting the same error.
mariohomework.c:26:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: mariohomework] Error 1

Comment: @Dackeriah If you have more than one statement in the body of a loop, you must enclose those statements in braces `{ }`. This answer doesn't show you the correct code. It's just showing you what the compiler sees.

Comment: aaaah okay thank you so much, I appreciate the assistance